# Material ui Autocomplete endInputAdornment custom elements not centered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When setting material ui `<Autocomplete />` with `variant='filled'` The endInputAdornments does not center to the AutoComplete.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-ully-j0hkd?file=/src/Demo.tsx) with both variants for reference here

```
<Autocomplete
    disablePortal
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={top100Films}
    sx={{ width: 300, mt: 2 }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Movie"
        variant="filled" //With filled it does not center anymore
        InputProps={{
          ...params.InputProps,
          endAdornment: (
            <React.Fragment>
              {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
              <IconButton
                color="primary"
                aria-label="upload picture"
                component="span"
              >
                <PhotoCamera />
              </IconButton>
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        }}
      />
```

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18463) where they fixed it for the inputProps internally but I cant seem to find a way to do the same with my own adornment elements.

The only prop that seems relevant is popupIcon but i still want that default feature. I just want to be able to add more IconButtons to the endInputAdornments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the container for the icon by using a `<div>` instead of `<React.Fragment>`:

```
              endAdornment: (
                <div style={{ marginTop: "-19px" }}>
                  {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                  <IconButton
                    color="primary"
                    aria-label="upload picture"
                    component="div"
                  >
                    <PhotoCamera />
                  </IconButton>
                </div>
              )
```

Here's the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-chatterjee-m8jih?file=/src/Demo.tsx)

Why -19px? Because with `variant="filled"` the container for the text and icon is shifted down by 19px:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is probably the best workaround, for future people use <Stack> from material-ui instead of <div> (if you want multiple custom endadornment elements)

Answer (score 2):

The popup icon of `Autocomplete` is vertically centered because of [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/353cecb5391571163eb6bd8cbf36d2dd299aaf56/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L193-L195) styles. You can add your own styles to center the icon next to it by modifying the styles from the source a bit:

```
<Autocomplete
  options={top100Films}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Movie"
      variant="filled"
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        sx: {
          // this is necessary if you don't want to input value to be
          // placed under the icon at the end
          '&&&': { pr: '70px' },
        },
        endAdornment: (
          <React.Fragment>
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
            <IconButton
              color="primary"
              sx={{
                position: 'absolute',
                p: 0,
                right: 40,
                top: 'calc(50% - 12px)', // Center vertically
              }}
            >
              <PhotoCamera />
            </IconButton>
          </React.Fragment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]